# window.cordova undefined on ionicPlatform.ready

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to show the object window.cordova by executing this code.

```
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    window.phonegap = {};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(window.cordova));
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
        cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }

    ngFB.init({appId: FB_APPID});

    if(window.StatusBar) {
        StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }

});
```

But i got undefined.

Comment: Have you included cordova.js file in your HTML?

Comment: Thank you, i forget to include the cordove.js and cordova_plugins.js in mobile my views.

Comment: cordova_plugins.js inclusion is not mandatory. Have posted the answer. Please accept so that it can be useful for others too.

Answer (score 2):

Include `cordova.js` file in your respective HTML and register for `deviceready` event which ensures cordova and its plugin loaded properly before invoking the same.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running this in you browser using `ionic serve`? Cordova is not compatible with browsers! It only works on phones. On your phone you would never have this problem. You can still see the command line output by running it as followed:

```
ionic run android -c -l
```

This also enables live updates, so you don't have to build the app each time you make a small change.

Comment: @Jur I dont believe in the statement that Cordova is not compatible with browsers.Infact Cordova does provide a seperare platform called browser like android and iOS

Comment: @Gandhi That's true, but it is a common mistake that people use ionic serve to test some cordova plugins

Comment: @Jur sorry I dint get that as I m not familiar with Ionic